# Отобразить картинку laravel

Tags: laravel

Загружаю картинку с вьюхи, картинка попадает как положено в storge->app->public->images. Я выполнил команду `php artisan storage:link`, но вот в чем соль. Картинки, которые уже были в моей папке `images`, до выполнения команды, попали в общедоступную папку `public`(там где лежат css и js), но новые загружаемые файлы попадают исключительно в папку (storge->app->public->images), соответственно их нет в папке `public` и вьюха не может получить к ним доступ как я понял.

Как это пофиксить?

Мне что, каждый раз после загрузки нового изображения прописывать команду `php artisan storage:link`?

Answer (score 0):

Команда `php artisan storage:link` создает симлинк в публичной папке (`/public/storage`) на директрорию `/storage/app/public` для того, чтобы к файлам был доступ из браузера.

Соответсвенно, если у тебя есть изображение `/storage/app/public/images/img.jpg`, то оно будет доступно из браузера на адресу `http://site.loc/storage/images/img.jpg`.

Каждый раз не нужно выполнять эту команду.